# cordova build minsdkversion error

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, phonegap-cli

I am getting a strange error when trying to build an empty phonegap project which has no additional plugins

```
Error: /home/arjun/Desktop/phone/goodbackup/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/home/arjun/Desktop/phone/goodbackup/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-74 Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [:CordovaLib] /home/arjun/Desktop/phone/goodbackup/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

I tried editing the config.xml and the android manifest xml to version 16, but it is still throwing the same `Build Failed` error

Using Phonegap 7.1.1. I had no issues building apps earlier, it is throwing this error unexpectedly now.

Plugin list

```
>$ phonegap plugin list
cordova-plugin-battery-status 1.2.5 "Battery"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.4 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.9 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.2 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.4.3 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.6 "Vibration"
```

Log output

```
>$ phonegap  build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android ' ...
Android Studio project detected


ANDROID_HOME=/home/arjun/Android/Sdk

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

studio

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Subproject Path: app

publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.


The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.


    at build_7cm3aseye2nga2tboifwbh2f7.run(/home/arjun/Desktop/phone/goodbackup/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:143)


Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.


:CordovaLib:preBuild

UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes
 NO-SOURCE

:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
 UP-TO-DATE

:app:preBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:app:preDebugBuild
 UP-TO-DATE

:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript
 NO-SOURCE

:app:compileDebugRenderscript
 UP-TO-DATE

:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
 UP-TO-DATE

:app:prepareLintJar
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
 UP-TO-DATE

:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
 UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
/home/arjun/Desktop/phone/goodbackup/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-74 Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [:CordovaLib] /home/arjun/Desktop/phone/goodbackup/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)



See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


:app:processDebugManifest FAILED



FAILURE: 
Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> 
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [:CordovaLib] /home/arjun/Desktop/phone/goodbackup/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,

        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,

        or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)


* Try:
Run with 
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
--debug option to get more log output.


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org


BUILD FAILED in 1s

23 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 22 up-to-date

Error: /home/arjun/Desktop/phone/goodbackup/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/home/arjun/Desktop/phone/goodbackup/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-74 Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [:CordovaLib] /home/arjun/Desktop/phone/goodbackup/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [:CordovaLib] /home/arjun/Desktop/phone/goodbackup/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a bug on the templates, I fixed it long time ago, but they didn't release a new version of the templates.

In your config.xml you'll find this preference:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="14" />
```

Just remove it or set the value to 16.

Comment: Going to `platforms > android > CordovaLib > AndroidManifest.xml` and editing the `minSdkVersion` handles the error.

Comment: Yeah, but it’s not recommend to do manual changes there, with the preference I mentioned you can set that value without manual modifications

Comment: Hmm..It was already set. Recently, I faced an error in build. Turns out I had removed a plugin but in the platform it still had a reference. To fix this, I removed the `android` folder itself and reinitialized the platform and plugins. I got a `Dex archives: setting .DEX extension only for .CLASS files` error. The manifest had set sdkVersion as 19, even though config.xml was complying with your answer. Manually editing manifest, had fixed the issue. I find this strange.